# passing context via fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having an issue instantiating a new object from a util class into a fragment class.
the instantiation requires passing a context but I fragment cant take context.

I have tried passing getActivity() but still getting a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION FOR GpsAssist.getLatitude(Since this is the first one to be called) error.

I am trying to call the methods getLatitude() and getLongitude() from the GpsAssist

Below is my code . could use all the help.

Thank you

MapsActivity Class:

```
 public class MapsActivity extends Fragment {


GoogleMap map;
private View view;
GpsAssist gAssist = new GpsAssist(getActivity());
double  lat = gAssist.getLatitude();
double lng = gAssist.getLongitude();


private final LatLng MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLng(lat, lng);

private LatLngBounds loc = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(37, -121), new LatLng(37,-121));

public void get(){


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_test, container, false);

    if(map == null){
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(MOUNTAIN_VIEW).title("Marker"));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(posi()));

    }else{

        //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(loc, 15));

    }


    return view;
}
public CameraPosition posi(){
    CameraPosition posi = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(MOUNTAIN_VIEW)
    .zoom(17)
    .build();
    return posi;
}




@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
       try{
            SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
                FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.remove(fragment);
                ft.commit();
                //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
              }catch(Exception e){
              }
            super.onDestroyView();
}







}
```

My GpsAssist Class:

```
  public class GpsAssist extends Service  {


//Primitive declarations
private double lat;
private double lng;
private String provider;

//Class instances
private Context context;
private Geocoder gCoder;
Location location;


public GpsAssist(Context context){

    this.context = context;
}


//Checking if GPS is enabled

LocationManager lManager;

public Location gpsConnected(){

    lManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean gpsEnabled = lManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkEnabled = lManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);



    if(! gpsEnabled && ! networkEnabled ){

    Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(i);
    }else {


         location = lManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);



        if(location != null){

             lat = getLatitude();
             lng = getLongitude();

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "Your location" + lat + " " + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();

            String addresses = getAddress(lat, lng, 2);
            Toast address = Toast.makeText(context, addresses, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            address.show();


        }else{

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot get your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }

    }
    return location;
}

//Method to find the best possible provider
public String getProvider(){

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //true means that only enabled providers will be returned
    provider = lManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    return provider;
}

public double getLatitude(){
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    return lat;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    lng = location.getLongitude();
    return lng;
}

public String getAddress(double lat, double lng, int maxR){

    String addres = "";
    gCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
    List<Address> address = gCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, maxR);

        if(address != null){

            Address adName = address.get(0);

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Address: \n");
            for(int i=0; i<adName.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                str.append(adName.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            addres = str.toString();
            System.out.println(addres);
        }else{

             addres = "Address is null";
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a service you can just use `this` as context, you dont need to give it context.

also you are using a service wrong. a service is started by an intent not by creating a new object

Comment: When I tried to change all the contexts to this and remove the constructor, it gave me an error on the main activity that "ContextWrapper.getSystemServices null pointer exception

Comment: How would I change the GpsAssist class to properly implement the getSystemservice()

Comment: remove `context.` from getSystemService you dont need that

Comment: removed constructor, removed context. and I am getting an error in my MainActivity which also calls getLat and getLng ERROR IS: caused by: Java.lang.NullPointerException  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:502)  any ideas why? I would like to understand how it works and not only a solution

Comment: probably because you are using the service wrong, read how to start a service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for your GpsAssist class, getLatitude() and getLongitude() reference the location instance variable, which it looks like is only populated by the gpsConnected() call.  Since you haven't called gpsConnected() yet, location will be null, resulting in your null pointer exception.  You could call gpsConnected() in your onCreate and move the calls getLatitude() and getLongitude() after the call to gpsConnected()